# Why can't I access certain nested JSON objects in React?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, api

Im trying to practice my React skills by building a simple fetch and render app. I'm using the Scryfall api to search MTG cards. I'm able to render properties like the name of the card and the artist but things like the prices and images are not rendering. 
Here's my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import scryfall from "../api/Scryfall";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import CardInfo from "./CardInfo";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { card: {} };

  onSearchSubmit = async (name) => {
    const response = await scryfall.get("/cards/named", {
      params: { fuzzy: name },
    });

    this.setState({ card: response.data });
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.data.prices.usd);
    console.log(response.data.image_uris.normal);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        <div>Found: {this.state.card.name}</div>
        <div>Artist: {this.state.card.artist}</div>
        <div>Price: {this.state.card.prices.usd}</div>
         <img
          src={this.state.card.image_uris.normal}
          alt={this.state.card.name}
        /> 


        <CardInfo card={this.state.card} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I console.log response.data.prices.usd or respsonse.data.image_uris.normal the price and image url print respectively. But, when I go to render them I get an error saying "can't read "usd"/"normal" of undefined". What am I missing?

Here's the API info:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "object": "card",
  "id": "bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679",
  "oracle_id": "09cc8709-fe10-472a-b05c-e89f3523018d",
  "multiverse_ids": [
    438576
  ],
  "mtgo_id": 65899,
  "mtgo_foil_id": 65900,
  "tcgplayer_id": 145297,
  "name": "Austere Command",
  "lang": "en",
  "released_at": "2017-11-17",
  "uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679",
  "scryfall_uri": "https://scryfall.com/card/ima/10/austere-command?utm_source=api",
  "layout": "normal",
  "highres_image": true,
  "image_uris": {
    "small": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/small/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.jpg?1562853529",
    "normal": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.jpg?1562853529",
    "large": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/large/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.jpg?1562853529",
    "png": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/png/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.png?1562853529",
    "art_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/art_crop/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.jpg?1562853529",
    "border_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/border_crop/front/b/e/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679.jpg?1562853529"
  },
  "mana_cost": "{4}{W}{W}",
  "cmc": 6,
  "type_line": "Sorcery",
  "oracle_text": "Choose two —\n• Destroy all artifacts.\n• Destroy all enchantments.\n• Destroy all creatures with converted mana cost 3 or less.\n• Destroy all creatures with converted mana cost 4 or greater.",
  "colors": [
    "W"
  ],
  "color_identity": [
    "W"
  ],
  "legalities": {
    "standard": "not_legal",
    "future": "not_legal",
    "historic": "not_legal",
    "pioneer": "not_legal",
    "modern": "legal",
    "legacy": "legal",
    "pauper": "not_legal",
    "vintage": "legal",
    "penny": "not_legal",
    "commander": "legal",
    "brawl": "not_legal",
    "duel": "legal",
    "oldschool": "not_legal"
  },
  "games": [
    "paper",
    "mtgo"
  ],
  "reserved": false,
  "foil": true,
  "nonfoil": true,
  "oversized": false,
  "promo": false,
  "reprint": true,
  "variation": false,
  "set": "ima",
  "set_name": "Iconic Masters",
  "set_type": "masters",
  "set_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/sets/741bcd30-7709-4133-8919-f4b46483bed7",
  "set_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Aima&unique=prints",
  "scryfall_set_uri": "https://scryfall.com/sets/ima?utm_source=api",
  "rulings_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/bef16a71-5ed2-4f30-a844-c02a0754f679/rulings",
  "prints_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=released&q=oracleid%3A09cc8709-fe10-472a-b05c-e89f3523018d&unique=prints",
  "collector_number": "10",
  "digital": false,
  "rarity": "rare",
  "card_back_id": "0aeebaf5-8c7d-4636-9e82-8c27447861f7",
  "artist": "Anna Steinbauer",
  "artist_ids": [
    "3516496c-c279-4b56-8239-720683d03ae0"
  ],
  "illustration_id": "7c6a01f8-e1f6-4fe4-b275-b2582be98783",
  "border_color": "black",
  "frame": "2015",
  "full_art": false,
  "textless": false,
  "booster": true,
  "story_spotlight": false,
  "edhrec_rank": 191,
  "prices": {
    "usd": "8.23",
    "usd_foil": "11.01",
    "eur": "6.04",
    "tix": "0.94"
  },
  "related_uris": {
    "gatherer": "https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438576",
    "tcgplayer_decks": "https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?contains=Austere+Command&page=1&partner=Scryfall&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "edhrec": "https://edhrec.com/route/?cc=Austere+Command",
    "mtgtop8": "https://mtgtop8.com/search?MD_check=1&SB_check=1&cards=Austere+Command"
  },
  "purchase_uris": {
    "tcgplayer": "https://shop.tcgplayer.com/product/productsearch?id=145297&partner=Scryfall&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardmarket": "https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Iconic-Masters/Austere-Command?referrer=scryfall&utm_campaign=card_prices&utm_medium=text&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardhoarder": "https://www.cardhoarder.com/cards/65899?affiliate_id=scryfall&ref=card-profile&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=card&utm_source=scryfall"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially your React component state has `state = { card: {} };`

But you are trying to read `image_uris` and `name` from `this.state.card` and they don't exist.

```
        <div>Price: {this.state.card.prices.usd}</div>
         <img
          src={this.state.card.image_uris.normal}
          alt={this.state.card.name}
        />
```

You might want to put an if statement and not render the component if those values are undefined.

For example in below code, I am checking to see if `this.state.card.name` exists before rendering the component.

```
  render() {

    if (!this.state.card.name) return null; 

    return (
      <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        <div>Found: {this.state.card.name}</div>
        <div>Artist: {this.state.card.artist}</div>
        <div>Price: {this.state.card.prices.usd}</div>
         <img
          src={this.state.card.image_uris.normal}
          alt={this.state.card.name}
        /> 


        <CardInfo card={this.state.card} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Reading the name and the artist from the JSON object works, it's specifically the image_uris and the prices which are nested objects. Without the "if" statement I can still render the name of the card and its artist.